# Extensions of $\Bbb Z_3$ by $PGL(2,q)$ where $q$ is odd

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $q$ be odd. If $G$ is a finite group such that $G$ has a normal subgroup $H$ of order $3$ such that $G/H\cong {\rm PGL}(2,q)$, what can we say about $G$. Is it true in general that $G\cong {\Bbb Z}_3\times {\rm PGL}(2,q)$?

The motivation for this question: If we change ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$ to ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$, then the result is true.

Comment: No, an element of order $2$ in ${\rm PGL}(2,q) \setminus {\rm PSL}(2,q)$ could invert the elements in $H$, giving a subdirect product of $D_6$ and ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$. But there are just two isomorphism classes of groups with this structure.

Comment: Many Thanks for the helps. Excuse me you mean that we conclude that $G\cong {\Bbb Z_3}\times {\rm PGL}(2,q)$ and one more which is a subdirect product of $S_3$ and ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$?

Comment: The last line of the question is not quite right. For ${\rm PSL}(2,9) \cong A_{6}$ has a non-split central extension with center of order $3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the Schur Multiplier of the perfect group ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ has order $2$, $G$ must have a normal subgroup $N$ of index $2$ isomorphic to $C_3 \times {\rm PSL}(2,q)$. Since ${\rm PGL}(2,q) \setminus {\rm PSL}(2,q)$ contains an element of order $2$, we have $G = \langle N,t \rangle$, with $t^2=1$. The direct factors of $N$ are both characteristic in $N$ and hence normalized by $t$, and clearly $\langle t, {\rm PSL}(2,q) \rangle = {\rm PGL}(2,q)$, so the group $G$ is determined by the conjugation action of $t$ on $H=C_3$.

There are two possibilities for that, $t$ can either centralize of invert the elements of $H$, giving two isomorphism classes of groups.

*Added later*: As pointed out by Geoff Robinson, the case $q=9$ is exceptional, because the Schur Multiplier of ${\rm PSL}(2,9)$ has order $6$. There is a third isomorphism class of groups $G$ in this case, which is a group with a normal series $1 < H < K < G$ with $|H|=3$, $K$ isomorphic to the perfect triple cover $3.{\rm PSL}(2,9)$, and $G/H \cong {\rm PGL}(2,9)$.
In this example, an element outside of $K$ inverts the elements of $H$.

Comment: Note that $q = 9$ is a case where there is already  non-split extension of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ by ${\rm PSL}(2,9)$ ( I mean by this a perfect triple cover of ${\rm PSL}(2,9)$).

Comment: I am sorry for this mistake. I consider that the Schur Multiplier is equal to 2. And for the second group in the above discussion we have $G\cong S_3\times {\rm PSL}(2,q)$, is this true?

Comment: I am very thankful for the complete and very useful comments.

Comment: Is there any difference between the character degrees of ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$ and this group?

Comment: What do you mean by "this group"? All of the groups we have been discussing have order $3|{\rm PGL}(2,q)|$ so the character degrees will certainly be different from those of ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$.

Comment: I am sorry I mean about a new character degree in one of them which does not exist in other one.